# Java Module-Info 'Uses' Directive (Service Consumption)

Tags: java, java-module, jpackage, java-17

I'm using one of the new random generator algorithms (https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/356):

`RandomGeneratorFactory.of("L128X1024MixRandom").create().nextDouble();`

And it works.
Except after using jpackage tool (https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/392)

###### I get exception

> No implementation of the random generator algorithm "L128X1024MixRandom" is available

I tried adding the `uses` directive to specify consuming the service in my module-info.java (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-7.html#jls-7.7.3)

`uses java.util.random.RandomGenerator;`

But that doesn't fix it or seem to matter being there (am I using it wrong? I would think this should be the solution).

Instead, I have to add jpackage option:
`--add-modules jdk.random`

## Repro Steps

#### 1. Create directories with files:

##### rngTest/com/example/Test.java

```
package com.example;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.util.random.RandomGeneratorFactory;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        try {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "nextDouble: " + RandomGeneratorFactory.of("L128X1024MixRandom").create().nextDouble());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Exception: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

##### rngTest/module-info.java

```
module com.example {
    requires java.desktop;
    uses java.util.random.RandomGenerator;
}
```

##### rngTest/manifest.txt

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Created-By: 17.0.1
Build-Jdk-Spec: 17
Main-Class: com.example.Test
```

#### 2. Run commands from the rngTest directory

(for macOS. Will need to change `--type dmg` for other platforms, see https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/392)

```
find . -name "*.java" > sources.txt
javac @sources.txt -d target
mkdir -p lib; cd target; jar cfm ../lib/test.jar ../manifest.txt *; cd ..
${JAVA_HOME}/bin/jpackage --module-path lib --module com.example/com.example.Test --type dmg --name Test
```

#### 3. Run the created installer, then run the installed application

Notice exception message.

Now rerun jpackage command with `--add-modules jdk.random` and then repeat step 3, notice success.

```
${JAVA_HOME}/bin/jpackage --module-path lib --module com.example/com.example.Test --type dmg --name Test --add-modules jdk.random
```

Comment: what does the complete command line read when you say it works?

Comment: @Naman Added repro steps

Comment: You have to run `jpackage` with `--jlink-options --bind-services`.

Comment: @Holger That works nicely, but it doubles my application size (77->154MB) compared to using `--add-modules jdk.random`, not sure what other services would be binding.

Comment: This could be connected to the fact that once you specify `--jlink-options`, it overrides the default options which are `--strip-native-commands --strip-debug --no-man-pages --no-header-files`. When you are at this tuning, you can also specify the compress option, i.e. `--jlink-options "--bind-services --strip-native-commands --strip-debug --no-man-pages --no-header-files --compress 2"`

Comment: @Holger Works great! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I had tried adding `requires jdk.random;` to my module-info.java

It failed to compile with error "module not found: jdk.random"

(I figured its access was limited with only exporting to java.base)

But that was with maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1

Turns out it does compile with javac and that works.

So maybe a bug with maven-compiler-plugin.

But I still think the `uses` directive should have worked. And I need to use the maven-compiler-plugin.